# Is mac address is changed when we change internet connection

Tags: networking

if i change my system internet connection form wired broadband to mobile packet data connection then myt system mac id will be same or getting changed? and if same then how to get active or working mac id

Comment: There is no such thing as a 'system MAC ID'. There is the MAC address of the adapter that is talking to the network. If you start using a different network you are using a different adapter and therefore a different MAC address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you connect to internet using different devices like for the wired broadband you use an ethernet card for that the Mac address is different and if you use wifi card for connecting to the internet its Mac address will also be different.All in all if you use different devices to connect to the interner your Mac address will change..
As its said on the above comments you can get the list using the command ipconfig in the command promt

Comment: exactly is there any way to identify my machine using unique mac id every time when i connect to internet with different usb modems or nic cards

Comment: I guess not because each device has a unique mac address that uses to identify themself when they connect to internet though you can change the mac address using some tweaks but cant get a static mac address id if you use different devices

Answer (score 0):

Normally they are different since they are different devices. If you are using Windows you can check the physical address of network interfaces with “ipconfig /all" in cmd.

Comment: using connection shouldn't affect the original MAC, your source of internet is changed not the machine you using to connect through!

Answer (score 0):

Your MAC address never changes. The MAC address is a unique number that the manufacturer of your device has put onto the device, so it will always be the same.

What you are referring to is an IP address. You typically get an IP address for your device and that allows you to send and receive data, like going on the internet or that. If you restart your device you will get a new IP address.

You can find out your IP address and even MAC address by tying ipconfig /all into the command line of your device